# Using binding path=. is disconnecting my binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using radio buttons which has the datacontext set to a observabelcollection of enums. When i am binding my radio buttons with path set to dot as shown below, data binding works for the first time the app comes up but then the data binding fails. If anyone knows why???

```
   <RadioButton  Content="No Model" FontSize="16" IsChecked= "{Binding Path=SisoModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.NoModel}}"/>
            <RadioButton  Content="Prediction Only" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SisoModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionOnly}}"/>
            <RadioButton  Content="Prediction And Control" FontSize="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SisoModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SISOModels.PredictionAndControl}}"/>
```

conversion code is here:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Enum), typeof(bool))]
    public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || parameter == null) return false;
            string enumValue = value.ToString();
            string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
            bool outputValue = enumValue.Equals(targetValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            return outputValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null || parameter == null) return null;
            bool useValue = (bool)value;
            string targetValue = parameter.ToString();
            if (useValue) return Enum.Parse(targetType, targetValue);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

model and view mode code is here:

public enum SISOModels
    {
        NoModel,
        PredictionOnly,
        PredictionAndControl
    };

```
public class SisoModels1 : BindableBase
{
    public SisoModels1(SISOModels _SisoModel)
    {
        SisoModel = _SisoModel;
    }
    public SISOModels SisoModel { get; set; }

}
```

within a for loop based on size of grid i have written below code, which will add these radio buttn user control(additionalSetup) into all cells of grid and set the datacontext:

```
 AdditionalSetup a1 = new AdditionalSetup();
                        a1.DataContext = vm.sisoModelList[ct];

                        ct++;
```

reason for going with observable collection is that we have to populate these radio buttons in all the cells of a grid and the grid size is available runtime. compile time am not sure how many radio buttons i am going to populate.

Comment: `IsChecked` probably shouldn't be bound to an `ObservableCollection`. That said, can you post the converter code? Do you ever see any `System.Data` binding exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to test, its hard to say for sure; but I'm pretty confident that the `return null` at the end of `ConvertBack` is killing your bindings.

The *correct* `ValueEquals` (Or `EnumToBoolean`) converter is:

```
public Convert(...)
{
    return value.Equals(parameter);
}
public ConvertBack(...)
{
    if ((bool)value)
       return parameter;
    else
       return Binding.DoNothing; //Not null!!!!
}
```

`Enum` types are value types, so unless you put a nullable wrapper around them, a null check is not usually necessary (feel free to add though).

More importantly, you should **not** be returning null out of this converter. Use `Binding.DoNothing` instead.

If you are binding *directly* against the `ObservableCollection` I'm guessing that is causing you a few issues as well, since it is obviously not an enum.

Comment: i changed the return value to binding.DoNothing still the issue remains

Comment: @Bharathkumar Unfortunately I can't debug your code. I would set breakpoints in the converter functions to see what is breaking, when. I still suspect that the `Binding=.` is causing problems if you are binding against an `ObservableCollection`. Perhaps try this on a simpler case and then add pieces in until it breaks.

Comment: i suspected that, hence changed the code (updatd above) to have collection of a class which has enum instead of collection of enums and the binding is to the property of that class (no dot been used now) still facing the same issue

Comment: @Bharathkumar It seems like you should be doing this with an `ItemTemplate` and that you are still going about the whole thing wrong. Why isn't this in an `ItemsControl`?

Comment: i had tried itemscontrol as well still have the same issue

Comment: @Bharathkumar You tried it with the fixed converter? I would try again with an `ItemsControl` with `IsChecked` bound against *an actual property with of that type of enum*. I don't see it *ever* working unless you have that kind of binding. Finally, I would re-debug the program and watch for any exceptions.